# Customise Python Cmd Module Default Error Message

Tags: python, cmd

I am building command-line utility, using python `cmd` module. Now I want change the default `*** Unknown syntax: ds` something like this `[-] Unknown command: ds`.

Is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply need to override the [`default()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.default) method:

```
class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def default(self, line):
        self.stdout.write('[-] Unknown command: %s\n' % (line,))
```